# Wordpress | images not show up equal after convert to responsive theme

Tags: wordpress, image, themes, responsive, equals

I converted my wordpress theme to responsive..
all values of "width" change to percents (%)

**and the poroblem is :**

from 400px width it show:

first line 2 post

second line just one post (instead 2 post)..

how can i fix that so the page will show 2 post in all line?

i attached some pictures to explain the situation.

[image of smartphone until 400px width](http://i67.tinypic.com/2cp9j5e.png)

[image of 500px](http://tinypic.com/r/2mw8sc7/9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok your situation was a little tricky. The theme was not really designed in the best way to make those "blocks" responsive. To make it work I added js to your footer (you can move this to a js file if you prefer)

```
<script>
function equal_cols(el)
{
  var divs = jQuery(el);
  divs.css('height', '');
  var tallestHeight = divs.map(function(i, al) {
      return jQuery(al).innerHeight();
  }).get();
  divs.css('height', Math.max.apply(this, tallestHeight));
  //alert(Math.max.apply(this, tallestHeight));
}

( window ).resize(function() {
  $('.products-row').each(function(){
    var el = $(this).find('.product-container');
    equal_cols(el);
  });
}).resize();

jQuery(window).resize(function() {
  columnConform();
});

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  columnConform();
});
```

Then in the movie-home.php and taxonomy-movie-genre.php file I commented out the "clears" that were being added every third row. We don't need that any more since we are making all the boxes the same size with JS.

```
<?php /* if(++$counter % 3 == 0) : ?>
  <div class="clear"></div>
<?php endif; */ ?>
```

The only gotcha is that all the boxes are the same size now regardless of how much content is in them.

Comment: Are you using a custom theme or a open source theme? You should checkout ngrok for porting your localhost. https://ngrok.com/

Comment: Gotcha, are you cool with customizing the template? I can give you a couple lines that should fix the responsive issue you are seeing.

Comment: See my updated answer below for a solution, let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Aww, looks like the "movie-home.php" uses the same code on line 38. If you add the counter code there as well it should work. I am almost 100% positive.

Comment: Ha, yea you don't want that. I updated the answer to a CSS only solution, so I would revert the counter and css change from before and just try this. It will change the layout to having the boxes at full width. Without access to your live project its a little hard to fully debug.

Comment: If you are cool with sending me a username/login here (http://andresthegiant.com/say-hello/) I can play around with it and see if I can get the effect that you want.

Comment: I would need admin access to add code to the appearance editor. I understand that it may make you uncomfortable. Give me a couple mins and I will try to do it without admin access.

Comment: Hey Tomer, thanks for trusting me. I updated the solution based on what I added/changed on your website.